# Returning info to controller from model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got this model function:

```
        public function set_news()
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');

            $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

            $data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'slug' => $slug,
                'text' => $this->input->post('text')
            );

            return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
        }
```

Where, as you can see, there is a variable called `$slug`. 
The way I call this function is through a controller:

```
public function create()
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/create');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

            }
            else
            {
                $var = $this->news_model->set_news();
                $this->load->view('news/SLUG/');
            }
        }
```

Now, what I'm trying to figure out how to do is use that `$slug` variable in the controller, to load the `view` of the article that was just posted - but I can't figure out how to access that variable after the data is submitted to the database.

Comment: try `return $slug`. and then `$this->load->view($slug);`

Comment: If I return slug then the data wont post to the database - because right now the return triggers putting the data into the database.

Comment: Why not call url_title() again, inside Controller?

Comment: `$this->db->insert()` where `insert` is function which is executing on your model, you are just returning the response of it.

Comment: `$this->db->insert()` returns TRUE or FALSE, that you don't check, when calling `set_news()` from Controller. So returning Slug from model can be also usable.

Comment: @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev This works, but now when I try to load the view I get an error like `Unable to load the requested file: news/createnews.php`. Why is it adding the .php at the end? Can I make that stop?

Comment: Maybe its returned by *url_title()* function? Check it. Also look your database, where you insert SLUG, does it insert .php extenstion to SLUG?

Comment: @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev No, it isn't.

Comment: Can you put code, how exactly create SLUG inside controller?

Comment: @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev I was able to fix it by replacing my `load()` with `redirect('news/'.$slug.'/');`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

controller

```
public function create()
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/create');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

            }
            else
            {
                $var['r'] = $this->news_model->set_news();
                $this->load->view('news/SLUG', $var);
            }
        }
```

model news_model.php

```
public function set_news()
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');

            $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

            $data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'slug' => $slug,
                'text' => $this->input->post('text')
            );

            $this->db->insert('news', $data);

            $id = $this->db->insert_id();

           return $this->db->get_where('news', array('id' => $id))->result();
        }
```

view news/SLUG.php

```
<pre>
    <?php var_dump($r);?>
</pre>
```